# Crystal Report data not displaying correctly

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having a problem with crystal reports because the records are not being displayed correctly. Below is the screenshot of the comparison between the crystal report output and the query from the database.

[image]

I would like to ask for a work-around or solution to this. I tried deleting the object and placing it again but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but still find it weird.

All that I have to do is to add this code and it will be back to normal

`lower(mtel_picnm)`

But I don't know why I need to do that. Any help on this? Just add in the comments to enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

The telephone number is not pulling from the field you have highlighted in your screenshot. You can see the name is pulling from that field as it has the trailing /

If the telephone number is pulling from the FAPT_TELNO field i'm a bit puzzled why the A is being translated to 0. Are you able to attach the report with the data saved?

Comment: Yes! The telephone number is pulling from the FAPT_TELNO field. But is there any way to resolve this? I checked the data type and they are set correctly.